# How do I get Burg on 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, burg

Burg themes won't install on Ubuntu 16.04, after adding the repository and trying to run apt-get update it just fails with "Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/n-muench/burg/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/main/binary-amd64/Packages   404   Not Found"
And I can't get through this to install any themes.

Answer (score 2):

Burg team has stopped its development and installing it on newer ubuntu versions is buggy.

I suggest you to continue using grub. Actually there are many good themes existing for grub. A few of them are

- http://www.deviantart.com/tag/grub2?offset=0
- https://github.com/Se7endAY/grub2-theme-vimix
- https://github.com/maximilienGilet/Elegant-GRUB2

Comment: give a try         https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer